# QGIS - Calculate area : different results between script and expression builder

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

When I run a script to calculate an area with `PyQGIS` I don't get the same result as when I calculate it with the `Expression Builder`.

Here is my script:

```
myLayer.startEditing()
myIndex = myLayer.fields().indexFromName("pyqgis")
for feature in myLayer.getFeatures():
    myLayer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), myIndex, round(feature.geometry().area()/10000, 4))        
myLayer.commitChanges()
```

Here is my expression :

```
 $area /10000
```

Both fields are in the same type and have the same precision
[image: Fields]

But result isn't the same.

[image: values]

I'm uing `QGIS 3.10.2 (LTR)`

[image: extent]

Comment: Which CRS is your layer in? Which extent do your features have?

Comment: This layer is in EPSG 2154 (RGF93 / Lambert-93). Extent is defined in provider but not in spatial extent. I have updated my post with a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you use a projected CRS

There are 2 ways to calculate the area using the field calculator.

1. using `area` which is always planimetric in the SRS of this geometry.
   From QGIS help:

> This differs from the calculations performed by the $area function, which will perform ellipsoidal calculations based on the project's ellipsoid and area unit settings.

2. using `$area`

Change your expression to: `area($geometry)/10000` (Edit: @Erik)

Comment: It should be `area($geometry)/10000`. Otherwise the expression wont work.

Comment: Great, i didn't know this (although it's written in help section, shame on me). This work great, thanks.